# C: ¿Cómo puedo hacer para de un buffer que he creado con fgets leyendo de stdin pueda asignarlo a un array de strings?

Tags: array, c, fgets

El caso es que no soy capaz de asignar correctamente lo que leo por teclado a un array de strings. Entiendo que parte del probelma es por como manejo los punteros y porqué guardo punteros a char en el array pero no se como hacerlo para guardarlo bien. A continuacion dejo una simplificacion del codigo para que entendais lo que digo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char buffer[1024];   //buffer para guardar lineas
    char *matriz[2];  //array de dos posiciones en la que guardo en cada posicion un puntero a char
    char *Comprobarfinal //string de referencia para no leer mas alla de EOL
    int poscion=0;


    Comprobarfinal= fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin); //Con esto leo por teclado
    while (Comprobarfinal != NULL){
    matriz[posicion]=buffer; //asigno el buffer a la primera poscion del array

    printf("%s",matriz[posicion]);//la primera vez si escribo hola por ejemplo devuelve hola si se repite el bucle y escribo adios me escribe adios correctamente pero en la poscion anterior tambien guarda adios

    printf("%s \n",buffer); //muestro el buffer
    posicion++;
    Comprobarfinal= fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin);
    }

    for (int p=0; p<3; p++){
        printf("\n%s",matriz[p]); //aqui es donde llega al for para mostrar y me muestra dos veces adios cuando tendria que mostrar hola y adios.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Por este motivo no puedo garduarlo bien el array y creo que es porque va cambiando lo que tiene el buffer y las tres posiciones del array apuntan a la misma zona de memeoria que es donde buffer y por eso solo se guarda lo ultimo. ¿Como podria hacerlo para no modificar el valor cada vez?
Gracias de antemano perdon si es absurda la pregunta acabo de empezar con C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de cada llamada a fgets, si no queremos sobrescribir el buffer, debemos comprobar cuantos caracteres hemos leído para así saber cual es la primera posición libre. Esa nueva dirección será la que usemos para el próximo guardado. Si no, estaríamos guardando en la misma zona la nueva string.

Con el siguiente código le pedimos al usuario dos entradas, dos strings, cada una con su carácter de fin '\0', y guardamos la dirección de inicio de cada una.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char buffer[1024];   //Buffer de 1024 bytes
    char *matriz[2];  //Array de char*
    char *bufferptr = buffer;  // En un inicio apunta a la primera posición de buffer
    
    int chars = 0;
    int position = 0;
    while (position < 2 && bufferptr < (buffer+1024) ) {
        fgets(bufferptr, 1024, stdin);
    
        matriz[position] = bufferptr; 
        chars = strlen(bufferptr);
        
        bufferptr = bufferptr+chars;
        position++;
    }
    
    for (int p=0; p<2; p++){
        printf("%s",matriz[p]); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

El array de punteros `char *matriz[2]` tiene solo dos posiciones por lo que el while será de dos iteraciones como máximo. Controlando también que no se haya llenado el buffer en la primera petición.

`bufferptr` es nuestro puntero auxiliar, la forma de actualizarlo es básicamente sumarle el número de caracteres de la string, obtenido mediante `strlen(bufferptr)`.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias me ha servido de veras tu explicación, ahora tengo claro como funcionan los punteros en C. Respecto lo del bucle while que comentas es cierto que daria bucle infinito pero es que se me olvido una linea de codigo que ya he editado, por eso no actualizaba la variable Comprobarfinal. Ahora ya veo lo que comentas de sumarle al puntero los caracteres leidos, tenia una idea de que eso se podia usar pero en este lenguaje no sabia como funcionaba exactamente. Muchas gracias de nuevo de verdad.